# how to use dates in String Values on cocoa pods line chart?

Tags: swift, charts, cocoapods, linechart

this is the code I get x and y values on line charts.

```
extension ViewController: CurrencyManagerDelegate {
     
     func didFailWithError(error: Error) {
     print(error)
     }
         func didGetTimeframeRates(_ timeFrameRates: [String : Double]) {
             
             let sortedRates = timeFrameRates.sorted(by: {$0 < $1})
 let keys = sortedRates.map {(self.formatter.date(from: $0.key)!.timeIntervalSince1970 as Double)}
             let values = sortedRates.map({$0.value})
             entries = []
             
             for item in 0..<keys.count {
                 entries.append(ChartDataEntry(x: keys[item], y: values[item]))
             }
             
             let set = LineChartDataSet(entries: entries, label: "Line Chart")
              
             set.colors = ChartColorTemplates.joyful()
              
              let data = LineChartData(dataSet: set)
              lineChart.data = data
DispatchQueue.main.async {
                 self.lineChart.notifyDataSetChanged()

                 }
             
         }
```

this is console output

```
[ChartDataEntry, x: 1671656400.0, y 19.803011, ChartDataEntry, x: 1671742800.0, y 19.907873, ChartDataEntry, x: 1671829200.0, y 19.912121, ChartDataEntry, x: 1671915600.0, y 19.901387, ChartDataEntry, x: 1672002000.0, y 19.855934, ChartDataEntry, x: 1672088400.0, y 19.850483, ChartDataEntry, x: 1672174800.0, y 19.886824, ChartDataEntry, x: 1672261200.0, y 19.951368, ChartDataEntry, x: 1672347600.0, y 20.04376, ChartDataEntry, x: 1672434000.0, y 20.04376]
```

Can I change these dates values into string or format them using dateFormatter and see them as real dates on x axis? how to do that?

and this is what I see on the chart:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to graph dates as X Axis (Swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50979448/how-to-graph-dates-as-x-axis-swift)

Comment: No but i found the solution. Thank you

Comment: @asduskun for other readers, please write an answer with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

i solved my problem by adding these lines to my delegate method

```
func didGetTimeframeRates(_ timeFrameRates: [String : Double]) {
             
             let sortedRates = timeFrameRates.sorted(by: {$0 < $1})
             let keys = sortedRates.map({$0.key})
             let values = sortedRates.map({$0.value})
             entries = []
             
             for item in 0..<keys.count {
                 entries.append(ChartDataEntry(x: Double(item), y: values[item]))
             }
```